# Как переписать регулярку, чтобы понимала кириллицу в js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Граница слова \b не работает с кириллицей. Как это выражение можно адаптировать к русскому языку?

```
let reg = /\b(красный|зеленый|green|yellow|purple|gray|blue)\b/gi

let str = 'Красный закат'

console.log(reg.test(str)); // вернет false

let str2 = 'blue sky'

console.log(reg.test(str2)); // вернет true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению граница слова \b не работает для алфавитов, не основанных на латинице. Проверка \b смотрит на обе стороны границы, должно быть \w с одной стороны и "не \w" с другой. Но \w означает латинскую букву (или цифру или знак подчёркивания), поэтому проверка не будет работать для других символов, в том числе для кириллицы.

Границу слова можно заменить на символы начала строки или пробел или табулицию. Это покрывает простых большинство случаев.

```js
let reg = /(^|\s|\t)(красный|зеленый|green|yellow|purple|gray|blue)($|\s|\t)/gi;

console.log(reg.test('Красный закат'));
reg.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(reg.test('blue sky'));
reg.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(reg.test('bluee sky'));
reg.lastIndex = 0;
console.log(reg.test('Красныйй закат'));
```

ps: вы используете модификатор g и test одновременно, не забывайте о lastIndex ;)